# Parsing error for XML created with WordPad

Tags: xml

I have created a simple xml file called "class" and saved it to my desktop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="class.xsl"?>
<class>
    <student>Jack</student>
    <student>Harry</student>
    <student>Rebecca</student>
    <teacher>Mr. Bean</teacher>
</class>
```

Then I created an xsl file to do some xslt called "class.xsl" and saved it to my desktop

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="class">
    <html>
    <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="student"/>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="student">
    <p>
    Found a learner!
    </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I click on the class.xml file and it trys to load it in internet explorer and gives me the following error:

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 

    Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Documents and Settings/nlamarca/Desktop/cla...

    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}}
    ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save it in text format. You have probably used MS Word or Wordpad or similar to edit the code. When you save it it is saves in the RTF format. This format is not suitable for the task you are trying to perform.

Either

1. Use another text editor, such as notepad, notepad++ etc.
2. Figure out how to save it in plain text format in your current editor

Comment: The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

System error: -2146697211. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Documents and Settings/nlamarca/Desktop/class.xsl'.

Comment: try running `regsvr32 msxml3.dll`

Comment: It has something to do with the Registry or some other application in your system. The xsl and xml both work fine.

Comment: I suspect the XSL has the same problem as the XML - you saved it as RTF rather than as text. Only guessing.